# javascript not showing div when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone please help me debugging my jquery scrolling up hiding the div

here is my javascript code

```
jQuery(function() { // document ready
        var sideBarTop = $('#sticky').offset().top; // position top
        var sideBarLeft = $('#sticky').offset().left //position left
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns scroll from top
            if(sideBarTop < windowTop) {
                $('#sticky').css({position: 'fixed', top: 210, left: sideBarLeft}).fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                $('#sticky').css('position', 'static').fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });

    });
```

here is my html code

```
<div id="sticky">
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="#avant">Avant</a></li>
    <li><a href="#allure">Allure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#eden">Eden</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

please someone help me

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pflores481/25Fxq/1/)

Comment: Can you please share code with JSFiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pflores481/25Fxq/1/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, can you please explain issue?

Comment: div id sticky not showing when scrolling up because of fadeout. can you please help me fixing it

Comment: I suspect that your whole approach is misguided. You can get a "sticky" sidebar using CSS alone. You probably do not need to use jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

Updated [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/25Fxq/4/).

Include below line.

```
    jQuery(function() { // document ready
    var sideBarTop = $('#sticky').offset().top; // position top
    var sideBarLeft = $('#sticky').offset().left //position left
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns scroll from top

        if(sideBarTop < windowTop) {
            $('#sticky').css({position: 'fixed', top: -40}).fadeIn("slow");

        }
       else     $('#sticky').css('position', 'static').fadeOut("slow");  

         setTimeout ( function() { $('#sticky').fadeIn("slow");  },1000);
    });

});
```

This is a patch for your existing code and it is not a recommended fix for you problem.